# RDP connection is too slow in Windows 11

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-11

I noticed that the RDP connection is too slow on Windows 11 (tested on several machines). On the same hosts with Windows 10 installed on VirtualBox, RDP works without delays. Tell me, please, is there a solution to this problem?

I tried

```
reg add "HKLM\software\policies\microsoft\windows nt\Terminal Services\Client" /v fClientDisableUDP /d 1 /t REG_DWORD
```

on the client, but this did not solve the problem.